# Access C# Variable From JavaScript

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a public property in my code behind named Tab which I'm trying to access in the pages aspx file with javascript but I'm not sure how to get the right value.

This gives me the value I want

```
alert('<% Response.Write(this.Tab); %>');
```

This does not

```
 var x = <% =this.Tab %>;
 alert(x);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Look at the generated source code and you will be enlightened (I hope)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you view the source you are probably seeing

```
var x = mystring;
```

I would guess you want the quotes too

```
var x = "<%= this.Tab %>";
```

Instead of having code inline, why don't you look at RegisterStartUpScript or RegisterClientScriptBlock.

Answer (score 2):

What about

```
var x = "<% =this.Tab %>";
```

?  It depends on what the value is of course, but you have to generate valid JavaScript.  Indeed, if it's a string, you'll probably want to do more than just quote it unless you have complete control over its value and you know for sure that the value itself won't contain a quote character.

Answer (score 1):

if `this.Tab` is a string instead of a number, the JS will break because you didn't put quotes around it in the second example.

```
var x = '<%= this.Tab %>';
alert(x);
```

Answer (score 1):

It will work

```
var x = '<% =this.Tab %>';
 alert(x);
```

Answer (score 0):

Two methods to do it, one is

```
    var y = '<%=this.Tab %>';
```

You can also use JavaScriptSerializer in the code behind and have a method to return value of your variable to javaScript code. This helps if you want to return your private data as well and also you can implement more logic to get the values if you want.

Your code behind-

```
    protected string GetTabValue()
    {
        // you can do more processing here
        ....
        ....
        // use serializer class which provides serialization and deserialization functionality for AJAX-enabled applications.

        JavaScriptSerializer jSerializer=new JavaScriptSerializer();
        // serialize your object and return a serialized string
        return jSerializer.Serialize(Tab);
    }
```

Your aspx page

```
    var x = '<%=GetTabValue()%>';
    // called server side method
    alert(x);
```

You can also user javascript eval function to deserialize complex data structures.

Answer (score 0):

For Razor following works.

`var x = '@yourc#variable';` 
`alert(x);`